# GeoWebCache missing Vector tiles

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, vector-tiles

I am using GeoServer 2.11.2 and GeoWebCache 1.11.1.

I try to generate vector tiles in pbf format. There is a lot of missing tiles in the result.

I try several things:

- set meta tiles to 1X1
- use one or several core
- try pbf and geojson format
- try version 2.11.1 of geoserver

I have more tiles in png for example.

Has someone had the same issue?

Comment: Can you make the problem to happen with some of the demo vector layers or can you provide some other dataset and SDL for reproducing the issue?

Comment: I have checked with the layer tiger_roads. I used the grid 900913. For example, for scale 5, I can generate a tile in png, but no one in pbf.

Comment: I have made the same test on a shape file, same data, and th eresult is good. It seem to be a postgis connection problem.

Comment: PostGIS driver may also do on-the-fly simplification which may have some effect on the result. Check the settings of you store and test.

Answer (score 4):

Turning off parameter `simplification on the fly` in the store configuration solves the problem.

Comment: Why downvote? Turning off the simplification solved the problem which was not obvious. It may also mean a bug in GeoServer.

Comment: would have been more obvious if you had mentioned using PostGIS in the question.